# Why I can't initialize a static const map in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-errors, stl

I want initialize a static const map in C++. But when I tried copy example to my code I got error like.

Code:

```
using namespace std;
struct A{     
static map<int,int> create_map()         
{           
map<int,int> m;           
m[1] = 2;           
m[3] = 4;           
m[5] = 6;           
return m;         
}     
static const map<int,int> myMap;
};
 
const map<int,int> A:: myMap =  A::create_map();
```

Error:

```
In function `std::numeric_limits<int>::min()':
multiple definition of `A::myMap'
first defined here
In function `void __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<int const, int> > >::destroy<std::pair<int const, int> >(std::pair<int const, int>*)':
multiple definition of `A::myMap'
first defined here
```

I don't have a second definition anywhere. Could it be related to my compiler? After commenting the line below, the code builds

```
const map<int,int> A:: myMap =  A::create_map();
```

Comment: [Cannot reproduce.](https://godbolt.org/z/3jP74aMTq) Can we have a [mre]?

Comment: If you put this code in a header file and included it multiple times, that would explain it. The variable definition bit should not be in a header file.

Comment: My guess is that you have `A::myMap` defined in a header file, and that header gets `#include`d into multiple translation units.  Thus `A::myMap` has multiple definitions; one per translation unit.

Comment: I moved const map<int,int> A:: myMap =  A::create_map(); to cpp file and it's works. Thanks